# re.match with '-' not working in python

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I have the following code

```
if(keys==14):
    print (values)
    result = re.match("(^\-)", str(values))
    print "RR is", result, (values)
```

but the match is not working for a sample line. Here is the output which I got
­

```
­-bob
RR is None ­bob
```

Comment: So what does `print repr(values)` produce?

Comment: `re.match(regex,string)` would return only the match object.

Comment: Also, how do you explain that `print (values)` produced `-bob` and `print "RR is", result, (values)` suddenly produces *just `bob` with no dash*. Your code cannot produce the outcome you show, not unless something else first did `sys.stdout.write(`-`)` before this part is run.

Comment: the 2nd line also had '-', was missed when i copied over here.Anyway when I did a repr(values) I see ­-bob
RR is None '\xc2\xadbob'  . So how do I match now

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce:

```
>>> x='-bob'
>>> re.match('(^\-)', x)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='-'>
```

Your `values` may be different, presumably by having non-printable characters in addition at the start.  Try printing a `repr` of it to make sure that's not the case...!

EDIT: and indeed the `repr` reveals that the `values` start with a soft hyphen (encoded in utf-8) which may sometimes display as a dash but isn't actually a dash.  RE matching encoded byte strings can be inconvenient, so let's first decode it into text:

```
>>> x = '\xc2\xadbob'  # or however else `values` is obtained as such
>>> y = x.decode('utf8')
>>> re.match(ur'([\xad-])', y)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1004c0af8>
```

(switched to Python 2 here which is why the repr of the match object differs from the above snippet, where I was using Python 3).  On a side note, I've dropped the redundant caret in the pattern (the `^` at the start) since the `match` method is **always** anchored at the start anyway.

The core ideas of course are: (A) use Unicode to work with what is semantically actual text rather than a string of bytes; (B) use `repr` to check what glyphs are actually there, rather than just what they may look like in some context (since non-displaying glyphs and look-alike ones may otherwise fool you); and (C) the `[\xad-]` part of the (unicode) RE pattern matches *either* a soft hyphen ('\xad') *or* an actual dash -- the dash must come second, right before the `]`, due to RE pattern syntax (otherwise it would indicate matching a range of characters, while we want to match an actual dash if that's what is present).

Comment: It's curious as to how `values` prints differently between the `print` statements...

Comment: Anyway when I did a repr(values) I see ­-bob
RR is None '\xc2\xadbob'  . So how do I match now

Comment: Aha, not a non-printable character but a one that can be "homonymous" to a dash -- specifically a "soft hyphen" (encoded in utf-8).  Well, then, you're probably better off decoding that byte-string to Unicode and working on that -- editing the answer to show it.

Comment: @veny99, you're welcome -- remember to *accept** the answer (click on the checkmark-shaped outline to its left).

Answer (score 0):

In using re.match("(^-)", values) and assigning it to result, we are not changing the 'values'. Therefore in both print statements the 'values' will be '-bob'.
The matched object will be in the 'result'

```
import re 
values = "-bob"
keys = 14
if(keys==14):
  print (values)
  result = re.match("(^\-)", values)
  print ("RR is", result.group(0), values)
```

Output

```
-bob                                                                                                                                                            
RR is - -bob
```